# Combobox listfillrange from 2 differents sheets

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I would like to fill a combobox with data from 2 differents sheets.

I have that function to create 2 ranges which works:

```
    Dim lst as Range
    Dim lst2 as Range
    Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BaseAliments")
    Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BaseRecettes")
    Set lst = Range(sht1.Range("A1").address, sht1.Range("A" & sht1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).address)
    Set lst2 = Range(sht2.Range("A1").address, sht2.Range("A" & sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).address)
```

But then when i try to fill the listfillrange :

```
  Set Ctrl =Worksheets("Menu").OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1")
  With Ctrl
      .Name = "CB"
      '.ListFillRange = 'Something to concatenate lst and lst2
  End With
```

- Union doesn't work between sheets
- I need to use ActiveX combo box (because they are writable)

Comment: That's a very unorthodox way to "create 2 ranges". The way you are doing it, you are trying to apply `Union` to a couple of strings. That won't work. Start by declaring `lst` and `lst2` as `Range` and then `set` them properly.

Comment: `Union` doesn't work with ranges from different worksheets.

Comment: This `.address` is not needed when setting the ranges.

Comment: Also, please get rid of the `ActiveSheet` reference and use an explicit reference to the worksheet where the combobox should be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **highly** recommend an approach using `For-Each` like the one Jvdv has demonstrated as it is easy, intuitive and elegant.

If however, you absolutely have to do it your way (combining two lists into one), then here's my suggestion:

```
Sub initializeCombo()
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim sht3 As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim lst1 As Variant
Dim lst2 As Variant
Dim lst3 As Variant
Dim i As Long

Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WS1") 'The worksheet where the first list is
Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WS2") 'The worksheet where the second list is
Set sht3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WS3") 'The worksheet where the ComboBoxt is

Set rng1 = sht1.Range(sht1.Range("A1"), sht1.Range("A" & sht1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set rng2 = sht2.Range(sht2.Range("A1"), sht2.Range("A" & sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

lst1 = rng1
lst2 = rng2

''''''''''''Combine the 2 lists into one'''''''''''''
ReDim lst3(1 To UBound(lst1) + UBound(lst2))        '
For i = LBound(lst1) To UBound(lst1) Step 1         '
    lst3(i) = lst1(i, 1)                            '
Next i                                              '
For i = UBound(lst1) + 1 To UBound(lst3) Step 1     '
    lst3(i) = lst2(i - UBound(lst1), 1)             '
Next i                                              '
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

sht3.OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Object.List() = lst3
End Sub
```

Finally if you want to programmatically create an `ActiveX` combobox in worksheet sht3 for example and assign it with `lst3` you have to do it like so:

```
    Dim Ctrl As Object
    Set Ctrl = sht3.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1").Object
    Ctrl.List() = lst3
```

**UPDATE**

JvdV's version modified to work with an ActiveX combobox would look like so:

```
Sub initializeCombo2()
Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet, sht3 As Worksheet
Dim lst1 As Range, lst2 As Range, cell As Range
Dim Ctrl As Object

Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BaseAliments") 'The worksheet where the first list is
Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BaseRecettes") 'The worksheet where the second list is
Set sht3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Menu") 'The worksheet where the ComboBoxt is
Set lst1 = sht1.Range(sht1.Range("A1"), sht1.Range("A" & sht1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set lst2 = sht2.Range(sht2.Range("A1"), sht2.Range("A" & sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set Ctrl = sht3.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1").Object

For Each cell In lst1
    Ctrl.AddItem cell.Value
Next cell
For Each cell In lst2
    Ctrl.AddItem cell.Value
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: it is Set rng1 = Range(sht1.Range("A1").address, sht1.Range("A" & sht1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).address), no ?

Comment: Not necessarily. It will work like that as well but strictly speaking, the `Range()` function takes as input two parameters of type `Range`. This `sht1.Range("A1")` is a `Range` while this `sht1.Range("A1").address` is a string.

Comment: But when i try to pass the range `sht1.Range("A1")`, I have an Error 1004 :  error 1004 method range of object _global failed

Comment: @Phoenix That happens probably because your code is located in one of your worksheet objects instead of a module. My bad. See updated code.

Comment: Thanks. I tried both, both works,I will use JvdV's version if it is more clean (and the combination version fail if one of the list contains only one cell)

Comment: Yes It is on my worksheet because i havn't found any other way to create the combobox on user cell select

Answer (score 2):

`Union` simply won't work over different worksheets. I think your best bet would be to individually add these items:

```
Set Ctrl = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddFormControl(xlDropDown, Left:=Cells(1, 1).Left, Top:=Cells(2, 1).Top, Width:=100, Height:=20)

With Ctrl
    .Name = "CB"
    For Each cell In lst
        .ControlFormat.AddItem cell.Value
    Next cell
    For Each cell In lst2
        .ControlFormat.AddItem cell.Value
    Next cell
End With
```

Comment: I have edited my code to really have lst as range. I tried as shown, but i get a "Run-time error: '438': Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: @Phoenix, check if the edited answer works for you. I added `.ControlFormat` as I forgot to do so in initial answer.

Comment: @JvdV I don't think `.ControlFormat` is supported by an `ActiveX` combobox.

Comment: @StavrosJon, edited to avoid use of ActiveX control (as they are a pain on a worksheet imo)

Comment: Yes but I need to use an ActiveX control because they are writable, and xlDropDown are not.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully populated the ListFillRange property in a ComboBox in a simple way.
I have a tab called "EQUIPMENT" that has tables of rental costs.  I selected the range I wanted to use and named it "LIST1" in the cell reference field on the worksheet. I then populated the ListFillRange property of the ComboBox (on another tab) LIST1.  Done.  I have several different List Fill ranges for different ComboBoxes, so my naming convention is LIST1, LIST2, etc.